# how to get the MAC address of client using ioctl function?

Tags: c, sockets

I want to capture the Client MAC address who are all request for my server. I use the following program to get the MAC address of the client but its showing "ioctl: Protocol Family Not Supported" . How to get the MAC address?..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<netinet/if_ether.h>
#include<net/if.h>
#include<linux/sockios.h>
int main()
{
  int socket1, socket2;
  socket1 = 0;
  socket2 = 0;
  struct sockaddr_in server, client;
  int returnstatus = 0;
socket1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if(socket1 == -1)
{
  perror("socket()");
}

server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons(8888);
returnstatus = bind(socket1, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
if(returnstatus == -1)
{
  perror("bind()");
}
returnstatus = listen(socket1, 5);
if(returnstatus == -1)
{
 perror("listen()");
}
for(;;)
{
  int buffr[4];
  int addrlen, n;
  addrlen = sizeof(client);
  socket2 = accept(socket1, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &addrlen);
    printf("%s\n",inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr));
    printf("%d\n",(int) ntohs(client.sin_port));
struct arpreq arpreq_;
bzero(&arpreq_, sizeof(struct arpreq));

if( ( n = ioctl(socket2, SIOCGARP, &arpreq_) ) < 0 ){
perror("ioctl");
}

unsigned char *ptr = &arpreq_.arp_ha.sa_data[0];
printf("MAC: %x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x\n", *ptr, *(ptr+1), *(ptr+2), *(ptr+3),
*(ptr+4), *(ptr+5));

if (socket2 == -1)
{
  perror("accept()");
}
returnstatus = read(socket2, buffr, sizeof(buffr));

if(returnstatus == -1)
{
  perror("read()");
}
int c[2]; 
int *w;
c[0] = buffr[0] + buffr[1];
w = c;
returnstatus = write(socket2, w, sizeof(c));
if(returnstatus == -1)
{
 perror("write()");
}
close(socket2);

}
close(socket1);
return 0;
}

int addition(int x, int y)
{
 int z;
 z = x + y;
 return(z);
}
```

Comment: What if the client is on another network, or even another subnet? Won't you only get the MAC address of the closes router then?

Comment: I want to get the Clients MAC who are in another network also or even anywhere in the world... How can I get it?..

Comment: You can't, really. The only sure way is to make the protocol used include a query from the server to ask the client to provide its own MAC address.

Comment: I want to get the Client MAC who are in same network atleast.. how can I achieve this?.. By using the above code i unable to get it..

Comment: For what purpose? There's nothing useful you can do with it. If you're thinking of using it as a system identifier, you need to consider that the MAC address can be changed by the user.

Comment: I have another validation internally. Hear what i want is the MAC address alone which needs to be sent to a PHP page..

Comment: @user1216216 So please explain the difference between 'another validation' and 'system identifier'.

Comment: I've to send the MAC address to another page. like http://testing.com/abcd.php?mac=--MAC---   => This will be the url. here I've to replace "--MAC---" with the MAC address of the client.  The client will be shown a login page. Then the client need to enter the login credentials to get access further..

Comment: What if the client has more than one network adapter and more than one MAC address?

Answer (score 4):

I have some code that seems to do what you want it to.

I have been trying to get some C++ code that will get the MAC address from a remote computer on my network. It took quite some time to figure this out. I managed to merge and modify several examples into a working demo. It should be very easy to modify this to work with a Socket connection.

This piece of code will take network device and IP address as arguments. 
(e.g. eth0 192.168.1.1)

The program will check the IP for correctness, then it will ping the IP address to add it to the ARP table, then it will extract the MAC address from the ARP table, then it will display the MAC Address.

I am not a C++ coder ( or at least I'm a newb ) so the code can probably be brushed up.

This code has been tested on Raspbian only!

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if_arp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sstream>


bool isValidIpAddress(char *ipAddress) {
    int result = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    result = inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress, &(sa.sin_addr));
    return result;
}

/**
 * @brief Convert String to Number
 */
template <typename TP>
TP str2num( std::string const& value ){
    std::stringstream sin;
    sin << value;
    TP output;
    sin >> output;
    return output;
}

/**
 * @brief Convert number to string
 */
template <typename TP>
std::string num2str( TP const& value ){
    std::stringstream sin;
    sin << value;
    return sin.str();
}

/**
 * @brief Execute Generic Shell Command
 *
 * @param[in]   command Command to execute.
 * @param[out]  output  Shell output.
 * @param[in]   mode read/write access
 *
 * @return 0 for success, 1 otherwise.
 *
*/
int Execute_Command( const std::string&  command,
    std::string& output,
    const std::string& mode = "r") {

    // Create the stringstream
    std::stringstream sout;

    // Run Popen
    FILE *in;
    char buff[512];

    // Test output
    if(!(in = popen(command.c_str(), mode.c_str()))){
        return 1;
    }

    // Parse output
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
        sout << buff;
    }

    // Close
    int exit_code = pclose(in);

    // set output
    output = sout.str();

    // Return exit code
    return exit_code;
}

/**
 * @brief Ping
 *
 * @param[in] address Address to ping.
 * @param[in] max_attempts Number of attempts to try and ping.
 * @param[out] details Details of failure if one occurs.
 *
 * @return True if responsive, false otherwise.
 *
 * @note { I am redirecting stderr to stdout.  I would recommend
 *         capturing this information separately.}
 */
bool Ping( const std::string& address ) {
    // Format a command string
    std::string command = "ping -c " + num2str(2) + " " + address + " 2>&1";
    std::string output;
    std::string details;

    // Execute the ping command
    int code = Execute_Command( command, details );
    return (code == 0);
}


static char *ethernet_mactoa(struct sockaddr *addr) {
    static char buff[256];
    unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *) addr->sa_data;

    sprintf(buff, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
        (ptr[0] & 0xff), (ptr[1] & 0xff), (ptr[2] & 0xff),
        (ptr[3] & 0xff), (ptr[4] & 0xff), (ptr[5] & 0xff));

    return (buff);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int s;
    struct arpreq areq;
    struct sockaddr_in *sin;
    struct in_addr ipaddr;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "-- Usage: %s device ipaddress\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Get an internet domain socket. */
    if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }


    if (!isValidIpAddress(argv[2])) {
        fprintf(stderr, "-- Error: invalid IP Address '%s'.\n",
             argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (inet_aton(argv[2], &ipaddr) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "-- Error: bad dotted-decimal IP '%s'.\n",
            argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Ping the Address for ARP table listing */

    if ( !Ping(argv[2]) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "-- Error: unable to ping IP '%s'.\n",
            argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Make the ARP request. */
    memset(&areq, 0, sizeof(areq));
    sin = (struct sockaddr_in *) &areq.arp_pa;
    sin->sin_family = AF_INET;

    sin->sin_addr = ipaddr;
    sin = (struct sockaddr_in *) &areq.arp_ha;
    sin->sin_family = ARPHRD_ETHER;

    strncpy(areq.arp_dev, argv[1], 15);

    if (ioctl(s, SIOCGARP, (caddr_t) &areq) == -1) {
        perror("-- Error: unable to make ARP request, error");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%s -> %s\n",
    inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *) &areq.arp_pa)->sin_addr),
    ethernet_mactoa(&areq.arp_ha));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ioctl(SIOCGARP)` You may get only MAC addresses of the local subnet, because SIOCGARP will return MAC addresses from the local ARP table.

You are using `SIOCGARP` little bit wrong way. Argument of SIOCGARP is an input-output type. So you must fill some fields of `arpreq_` before calling `ioctl`.
See [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/arp).

When the peer is out of your ethernet subnet, then traffic goes via router, and the peer may be in ethernet network or not (example: mobile phones). So it can be impossible to get ethernet MAC address from every peer.

When you host communicates with peer, MAC address of the first router is used.